# serial (and/or parallel) port communication simulation with virtual machine

Tags: driver, simulation, virtual-machine, ports

I am making a windows upper filter driver for serial and parallel ports.
I want to test it in a virtual machine and I need some sort of software that can simulate communication over these ports with the VM. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox 4 can emulate a serial port on the emulated system and write to e.g. a named pipe. Using ([VMWareGateway](http://www.l4ka.org/91.php), you can proxy this to a network port. Then use ncat or whichever tool you want to play with the connection...

As for parallel ports, VirtualBox doesn't support this, but IIRC, apparently there was some code started for parallel support. You might want to search the forums at the virtualbox site.